# Cannot fetch items from hash, get Global symbol requires explicit package name

Tags: perl

I try to work with hashes in Perl.

I have following example:

```
my %ERROR_CODE_101 = ("id"  => 101,"desc" => "blablabla");

sub checkError
{   
   # some switch-case 
   #....
   return %ERROR_CODE_101;    
}

sub runCommand
{        
    my $code = checkError();
    if($code{id} > 0)    # error happens here line 216
    {
       #...
    }
}
```

Error:

> Global symbol "%code" requires explicit package name at build_ios.pl
>   line 216.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`my $code = checkError();` assigns the return value to the **scalar** `$code`.

`$code{id}` tries to read the **scalar** `id` value from the `%code` **hash** … but you have a scalar, not a hash.

You need to assign the return value to a hash in the first place:

```
my %code = checkError();
```